# Prove that $\mathbb{C}$ with its usual complex absolute value $|\cdot |$ is complete.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, analysis, cauchy-sequences

I know in order to prove that $\mathbb{C}$ is complete in need to show that its Cauchy Sequences converges, but I don't have an background in complex sequences so I don't know where to start regarding how to show they converge.

Comment: What is the difference from $\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: $\mathbb{C}$ is the set of numbers of the form a+bi where $a,b \in \mathbb{R}$. I'm not sure if this is a hint or you are asking me

Comment: It was a hint. There is even a better way: we know that if $z_n=x_n+iy_n$, then $z_n$ converges iff both $x_n$ and $y_n$ converge. So, if you show that if $z_n$ is Cauchy then $x_n$ and $y_n$ are Cauchy, you're done.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you know that $\mathbb{R}$ is complete, check that the following statements hold:

1. A sequence of complex numbers $(a_n + ib_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ with $a_n, b_n \in \mathbb{R}$ converges to $a + ib$ ($a, b \in \mathbb{R}$) if and only if $(a_n)_n \to a$ and $(b_n)_n \to b$ as real sequences.
2. A sequence of complex numbers $(a_n + ib_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ with $a_n, b_n \in \mathbb{R}$ is a Cauchy sequence if and only if $(a_n)_n$ and $(b_n)_n$ are real Cauchy sequences.

Note that the completeness of $\mathbb{C}$ now readily follows from $\mathbb{R}$'s completeness.